# friend function name visible in class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend, friend-function

Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    public:
        friend void f() {}
        friend void f(C<T>) {}
};

C<int> c;

void g(C<int>* p)
{
     f(); 
     f(*p);
}
```

Compiling with GCC 5.2 throws the following compile error:

```
no matching function for call to 'f()'
```

But the standard says in 14.6.5:

> Friend classes or functions can be declared within a class template.
>   When a template is instantiated, the names of its friends are treated
>   as if the specialization had been **explicitly declared** at its point of instantiation.

Why does this fail to compile? In GCC 3.4, it passes.

Comment: please note that, if a template is instantiated, its friends are treated declared, **which means friend name is visible**.  I know the second one can be found by ADL

Answer (score 3):

`f` can only be found via argument-dependent name lookup (ADL). The second call compiles because the pointee of `p`, which is passed as an argument, is of type `C<int>` - this causes ADL to jump in and inspect otherwise invisible functions. In fact, the first overload of `f` can't be found at all, as there is no way of conveying an association to any specialization of `C`.

Just see the quote right after yours, [[temp.inject]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inject#2):

> As with non-template classes, the names of namespace-scope friend functions of a class template specialization
>   are **not visible during an ordinary lookup unless explicitly declared at namespace scope (11.3)**. Such names
>   may be found under the rules for associated classes (3.4.2). <sup>141</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>141)</sup> **Friend declarations do not introduce new names into any scope, either when the template is declared or when it is
>   instantiated.**

Comment: your said is right. But my questions is not ADL. I really want to know  why compile are not line with C++ specification( instantiated means friend visible).

Comment: @zpeng "Instantiated means friend visible" is nonsense.

Comment: I cannot understand what's real mean in C++ specification("When a template is instantiated, the names of its friends are treated as if the specialization had been explicitly declared at its point of instantiation.").

Comment: @zpeng You're misinterpreting that quote. It is not making the `friend`s generally visible. And GCC 3.4 is horribly bugged, so don't base your understanding of the language on that completely outdated version.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `f()` is in no way associated with class `C`, so its friends are not used in the overload resolution.

In the other call, `f(*p)`, the parameter is of class type and therefore the class and the namespace of the class are checked for possible candidates. That way the compiler will find both `f` functions and use overload resolution to select the proper one.